# computes the $\phi$ angle of an ellipse

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections, curves

I've an ellipse that is rotated and not centered in the origin. Hence, I've an ellipse equation that is in the form of:

\begin{equation}
\frac{((x-h)cos(\phi) + (y-k)sin(\phi))^2}{a^2} + \frac{((x-h)sin(\phi) - (y-k)cos(\phi))^2}{b^2} = 1
\end{equation}
Suppose that I know the foci, the center and a and b, how can find $\phi$ ?

Comment: You mean that you have $h,k,a,b$ and the foci right? If I am right, then you can know easily enough the 4 vertices of the ellipse so you can substitute $x$ and $y$ and get some equations having only $\phi$ as an unknown

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply.
Yes, I know $h$, $k$, $a$, $b$ and foci. If you are right how can I derive the vertices from these information?

Comment: If you know the foci, then you’re basically done: they lie on the semimajor axis.

Comment: If you know the center and the foci then you can get the equation of this line joining the center with the foci (the major axis) and you know that the distance from then center to the a vertex on the ellipse is $a$ so you get the coordinates of 2 vertices by this method

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try. However, if I know the foci, is it possible to get the angle $\phi$, computing the equation of the line passing through the foci and getting the slope of that line?

Comment: Yes: the slope of that line is precisely $\tan\phi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody.